# Xcode add macro

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I used [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) add macro for xcode project (not Pods target), I have tried like this in Podfile.

```
 def add_macro
  require 'xcodeproj'
  project_path = './Nuclear.xcodeproj'
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
  project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Nuclear'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        old_gcc_settings = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
        puts "⭕️target:#{target} config:#{config} GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS:#{old_gcc_settings}"
        old_gcc_settings ||= ['$(inherited)']
        old_gcc_settings << 'XXX_TEST_MACRO=1'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = old_gcc_settings
        puts"target:#{target} config:#{config} GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS:#{config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']}"
      end
    end
  end
end

pre_install do |installer|
  add_macro
end
```

when I run `pod install`, It's print right, but the project target does not have macro that I want to add.

Is there any way can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `project save` at the end of method `add_macro`.Like below:

```
def add_macro
  require 'xcodeproj'
  project_path = './Nuclear.xcodeproj'
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
  project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Nuclear'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        old_gcc_settings = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']
        puts "⭕️target:#{target} config:#{config} GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS:#{old_gcc_settings}"
        old_gcc_settings ||= ['$(inherited)']
        old_gcc_settings << 'XXX_TEST_MACRO=1'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = old_gcc_settings
        puts"target:#{target} config:#{config} GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS:#{config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS']}"
      end
    end
  end
  project.save
end

pre_install do |installer|
  add_macro
end
```